# How can user stop async method?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

How to implement mechanism that allows user to stop async method in MVC?

I have idea to make it in that way:

```
public string stopToken { get; set; }
public int iteration { get; set; }

public async Task<string> someActionAsync()
{
    do
    {
        iteration++;
        await SomeService.SomeMethod();
    } while (stopToken != "true");

    return "Complete";
}

public void Stop(string token)
{
    this.stopToken = token;
}

public int returnIteration()
{
    return this.iteration;
}
```

On frontend:
User call with ajax `someActionAsync` method. Action to infinity is already set (do => while). User can stop that action by clicking button `Stop` (and by calling method `Stop` with jquery ajax).

I just have to know that this is proper way to do it. Or maybe there is another (better) solution.

Comment: That's can't work with multiple users; you need session state.

Comment: can you explain why? With session state I will have `while (Session["token"] != "true")` instead of `while (stopToken != "true")`?(the same with Stop method) Am I right?

Comment: That will give you a compiler warning; you need a cast.  You also need to do that for all state.

Comment: yeah, that's obvious, but I'm asking generally is this correct way now.

Comment: Hmm; actually, that won't work either, because of the session lock.  You need something more complicated.  (eg, a `ConcurrentDictionary` of cookie IDs)

Comment: Can you explain me why session lock will appear? About cookie: so, with method `Stop` I have to set cookie (as I understand I can do this with `ajax`), put it in `ConcurrentDictionary<int, HttpCookie>` with key=1 and then `while` code will look like: `while(xyz.TryGetValue(1))`. Am I right now?

Comment: Session lock is always there while a request for given browser session is being handled (in your case - will never be released since your action runs forever). To clarify your problem for you - you need to be able to find particular long running operation from next request - hard as 2 requests even from the same browser have no relationship to each other. You either need registry of operations OR keep coming into the same "requests" i.e. with WebSockets or SignalR.

Comment: shame to say, but can you explain in an easier way that problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are close but there is a built in capability for this:  CancellationToken.  By using that instead of your own thing, your code can play nicer with other .NET APIs.  Here's an MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) on using it

Comment: Are there any examples for an actual MVC application, allowing the user to cancel a task?
I still didn't understand how is the implementation of the question above, using CancellationToken.
Basicly I didn't understand yet how we can pass the Cancellation request from the user to the Stop action.